# Восстановление порядка элементов на прямой по матрице расстояний с помощью PCA

Tags: python, numpy

Добрый день. У меня есть матрица расстояний между  n элементами на прямой, размерность матрицы n x n, например pair_distances:

```
pair_distances

[[ 0.  3.  6.  1.]
[ 3.  0.  5.  2.]
[ 6.  5.  0.  5.]
[ 1.  2.  5.  0.]]
```

Нужно восстановить порядок, в котором элементы располагаются на прямой. Например, для данной матрицы [e1, e4, e2, e3], элементы пронумерованы по порядку как в матрице. Данные не стопроцентно точны, поэтому многие стандартные алгоритмы не сработали. Предложили идею снизить размерность массива с помощью PCA.

Я попробовала сделать это на представленной табличке

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=1)
PCAreduced = pca.fit_transform(pair_distances)
print 'Sklearn reduced: \n', PCAreduced
```

Вот что получила:

```
Sklearn reduced: 
[[-2.91964806]
[-1.12020198]
[ 6.57986373]
[-2.54001369]]
```

Я не совсем понимаю, как это можно соотнести с порядком или для какого именно элемента тут отображены его парные расстояния? Можно ли с этим работать?

Comment: не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить... У вас были точки для которых вы посчитали матрицу расстояний (пока непонятно - для какой цели). `Нужно восстановить порядок, в котором элементы располагаются на прямой` - вы можете перефопмулировать так, чтобы было понятнее? Может стоит начать с начала: имеем массив координат (пример в вопросе), надо получить то-то и то-то (пример в вопросе)...

Comment: @MaxU, матрица расстояний нужна именно для восстановления порядка элементов на прямой. скажем, у нас есть ось х, на ней первым располагается элемента a, потом f, k, j. Расстояния меожду ними соответственно 2,1, 5. Пусть расстояния аддитивны, можно восстановить матрице попарных расстояний между всеми элементами.
У меня обратная задача - по матрице понять какой элемент где на оси находится. Но матрица в жизни на самом деле только приближенная, поэтому на аддитивность расстояний можно рассчитывать тоже только приближенно. Жадные алгоритмы не работают,  вот предложили сделать с PCA.

Comment: хммм, интересная задачка... а какой результат вы ожидаете для предложенной матрицы? Можете его [в вопросе указать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/628717/edit)?

Comment: PCAreduced порядок для примера правильный показывает. Осталось только argsort сделать.